# Converting CMD script to GUI

Tags: user-interface, batch-file, version-control

I have a question.

I'm currently trying to convert a simple batch script that I have made to a GUI-version. I'm not a professional, but I love to tinker around and try stuff out.

Is there anyone who could help me to go in the right direction?
Here is my simple batch script:

```bash
@echo off
::BatchHasAdmin
:-------------------------------------
REM --> Check if this file has administrator rights.
    IF "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%" EQU "amd64" (
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\SysWOW64\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\SysWOW64\config\system"
) ELSE (
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"
)

REM --> If no rights, we don't have setted the flag for it.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
    echo Requesting administrative privileges...
    goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    set params= %*
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/c ""%~s0"" %params:"=""%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    exit /B

:gotAdmin
    pushd "%CD%"
    CD /D "%~dp0"
:--------------------------------------    
:: MainCode
@echo off
title pcHealth - Check your PC's Health! - version 1.5.7-beta
cd /
color D
cls

:MENU
cls
color D
echo.
echo Thanks for downloading and using pcHealth!
echo Please be sure that you are running this Batch file in Administrator mode.
echo.
echo Made by REALSDEALS - Licensed under GNU-3 (You are free to use, but not to change or to remove this line.)
echo You are now using version 1.5.7 (Beta)
echo.
echo %DATE%, %TIME%
echo.
echo ...........................................................
echo Enter number 1 to open a menu regarding testing scripts.
echo Enter number 2 to open a menu regarding programs for testing /w downloadable redirects.
echo Enter number 3 to go to the repository of pcHealth.
echo Enter number 4 to close this batch script.
echo ...........................................................
echo.

SET /P A=Type one of the numbers from the menu above to open the desired menu and then press ENTER. Enter: 
IF %A%==1 GOTO TOOLS
IF %A%==2 GOTO PROGRAMS
IF %A%==3 GOTO PCHEALTHGETVER
IF %A%==4 GOTO CLOSE

:TOOLS
cls 
color 9
echo.
echo ...........................................................
echo Enter number 1 to gather generic information about the system.
echo Enter number 2 to see which CPU and GPU are in the system.
echo Enter number 3 to run a system scan for missing/corrupt files.
echo Enter number 4 to try and repair missing/corrupt files.
echo Enter number 5 to run a system scan and to start an attempt on repairing missing/corrupt files.
echo Enter number 6 to generate a battery report. (Laptop only)
echo Enter number 7 to open the GUI to Windows Updates.
echo Enter number 8 to start a short ping test.
echo Enter number 9 to start a continues ping test.
echo Enter number 10 to update system programs.
echo Enter number 11 to re-start the audio drivers of your system.
echo Enter number 12 to re-open the generated battery report file.
echo Enter number 13 to re-open the CBS.log (AKA DISM.log)
echo Enter number 14 to get your Ninite! Includes Edge, Chrome, VLC and 7Zip.
echo Enter number 15 to see your systems Windows License key.
echo Enter number 16 BIOS Password Recovery.
echo Enter number 17 to shutdown, reboot or log off from your PC/laptop.
echo Enter number 18 to open the programs menu.
echo Enter number 19 to return to the previous menu.
echo Enter number 20 to close this batch file.
echo ...........................................................
echo.

SET /P B=Type one of the numbers from the menu above to run the desired function, then press ENTER. Enter: 
IF %B%==1 GOTO SYSINFO
IF %B%==2 GOTO CPUANDGPUINFO
IF %B%==3 GOTO SCAN
IF %B%==4 GOTO DISM
IF %B%==5 GOTO SCSM
IF %B%==6 GOTO BATTERY
IF %B%==7 GOTO UPDATE
IF %B%==8 GOTO SHORTPING
IF %B%==9 GOTO CONTINUESPING
IF %B%==10 GOTO SYSUPDATE
IF %B%==11 GOTO AUDIORE 
IF %B%==12 GOTO BATOPEN
IF %B%==13 GOTO OPENCBSLOG
IF %B%==14 GOTO NINITE
IF %B%==15 GOTO LICENSE
IF %B%==16 GOTO BIOSPW
IF %B%==17 GOTO RESHUT
IF %B%==18 GOTO PROGRAMS
IF %B%==19 GOTO MENU
IF %B%==20 GOTO CLOSE

:PROGRAMS
cls
color B
echo.
echo ...........................................................
echo Enter number 1 to get hardware info.
echo Enter number 2 to get ADW Cleaner.
echo Enter number 3 to get DiskInfo64.
echo Enter number 4 to get DiskMark64.
echo Enter number 5 to get Prime95.
echo Enter number 6 to open the tools menu.
echo Enter number 7 to return to the previous menu.
echo Enter number 8 to close the script.
echo ...........................................................
echo.

SET /P AB=Type one of the numbers above to run the desired function. Enter: 
IF %AB%==1 GOTO HARDINFODOWN
IF %AB%==2 GOTO ADWCLEANER
IF %AB%==3 GOTO DISKINFODOWN
IF %AB%==4 GOTO DISKMARKDOWN
IF %AB%==5 GOTO PRIMEDOWN
IF %AB%==6 GOTO TOOLS
IF %AB%==7 GOTO MENU
IF %AB%==8 GOTO CLOSE

:SYSUPDATE
cls
color A
winget upgrade --all
pause
echo.
SET /P LL=Enter number 1 to return to the sub-menu, enter number 2 to return to the main-menu or enter number 3 to exit the script. Enter: 
IF %LL%==1 GOTO TOOLS
IF %LL%==2 GOTO MENU
IF %LL%==3 GOTO CLOSE

:SYSINFO
cls
color A
systeminfo
pause
echo.
SET /P C=Enter number 1 to return to the main-menu, enter number 2 to go back to the previous sub-menu or enter number 3 to close the script. Enter: 
IF %C%==1 GOTO MENU
IF %C%==2 GOTO TOOLS
IF %C%==3 GOTO CLOSE

:SCAN
cls
color A
sfc /scannow
pause
echo.
SET /P D=If the scan found any corrupt files, enter number 1 to check the .log, enter number 2 to return to the previous sub-menu, enter number 3 when you want to return to the menu or enter number 4 to close the script. Enter: 
IF %D%==1 GOTO OPENCBSLOG
IF %D%==2 GOTO TOOLS
IF %D%==3 GOTO MENU
IF %D%==4 GOTO CLOSE

:CPUANDGPUINFO
cls
color A 
echo. 
echo Your CPU information:
echo.
wmic cpu get caption, deviceid, name, numberofcores, maxclockspeed, status
echo.
echo Your GPU information:
echo.
wmic path win32_VideoController get name
pause
echo.
SET /P E=Enter number 1 to return to the main-menu, enter number 2 to go back to the previous sub-menu or enter number 3 to close the script. Enter: 
IF %E%==1 GOTO MENU
IF %E%==2 GOTO TOOLS
IF %E%==3 GOTO CLOSE

:DISM
cls
color A
DISM /online /cleanup-image /checkhealth
DISM /online /cleanup-image /scanhealth
pause
echo.
SET /P F=Enter number 1 to start an attempt on repairing, enter number 2 to return to the previous sub-menu, number 3 for the main-menu or number 4 to exit the script. Enter: 
IF %F%==1 GOTO DISMRESTORE
IF %F%==2 GOTO TOOLS
IF %F%==3 GOTO MENU
IF %F%==4 GOTO CLOSE

:DISMRESTORE
cls
color A
DISM /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth
pause
echo.
SET /P G=Enter number 1 to return to the main-menu, enter number 2 to go back to the previous sub-menu or enter number 3 to close the script. Enter: 
IF %G%==1 GOTO MENU
IF %G%==2 GOTO TOOLS
IF %G%==3 GOTO CLOSE

:SCSM
cls
color A
sfc /scannow
pause
echo.
SET /P H=If the scan found any corrupt files, enter number 1 to check the .log, enter number 2 to start an attempt to repair the corrupt/missing files,enter number 3 to return to the previous sub-menu, enter number 4 to return to the main-menu or enter number 5 to exit the script. Enter: 
IF %H%==1 GOTO SCSMOPENLOG
IF %H%==2 GOTO CONTINUE
IF %H%==3 GOTO TOOLS
IF %H%==4 GOTO MENU
IF %H%==5 GOTO CLOSE

:SCSMOPENLOG
cls
color A
start %windir%\explorer.exe "C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log"
pause
echo.
SET /P I=Enter number 1 to start an attempt to repair the corrupt/missing files, if any are found... Enter number 2 to return to the previous sub-menu, enter number 3 to return to the main-menu or enter number 4 to exit the script. Enter: 
IF %I%==1 GOTO CONTINUE
IF %I%==2 GOTO TOOLS
IF %I%==3 GOTO MENU
IF %I%==4 GOTO CLOSE

:CONTINUE
cls
color A
DISM /online /cleanup-image /checkhealth
DISM /online /cleanup-image /scanhealth
pause
DISM /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth
pause
echo.
SET /P J=Enter number 1 to return to the previous sub-menu, enter number 2 to return to the main-menu or enter number 3 to exit. Enter: 
IF %J%==1 GOTO TOOLS
IF %J%==2 GOTO MENU
IF %J%==3 GOTO CLOSE

:BATTERY
cls
color A
powercfg /batteryreport
pause
echo.
SET /P K=Enter number 1 to open the generated file, enter number 2 to return to the previous sub-menu, number 3 to return to the main-menu or enter number 4 to exit the script. Enter: 
IF %K%==1 GOTO BATOPEN
IF %K%==2 GOTO TOOLS
IF %K%==3 GOTO MENU
IF %K%==4 GOTO CLOSE

:UPDATE
cls
color A
control update
pause
echo.
SET /P L=Enter number 1 to return to the previous sub-menu, enter number 2 to return to the main-menu or enter number 3 to exit the script. Enter: 
IF %L%==1 GOTO TOOLS
IF %L%==2 GOTO MENU
IF %L%==3 GOTO CLOSE

:SHORTPING
cls
color A
ping 8.8.8.8 
pause
echo.
SET /P M=Enter number 1 to return to the previous sub-menu, enter number 2 to return to the main-menu, enter number 3 to start a continues ping test or enter number 4 to exit the script. Enter: 
IF %M%==1 GOTO TOOLS
IF %M%==2 GOTO MENU
IF %M%==3 GOTO CONTINUESPING
IF %M%==4 GOTO CLOSE

:CONTINUESPING
cls
color A
ping 8.8.8.8 -t -l 256
pause
echo.
SET /P N=Enter number 1 to return to the previous sub-menu menu, enter number 2 to return to the main-menu or enter number 3 to exit the script. Enter: 
IF %N%==1 GOTO TOOLS
IF %N%==2 GOTO MENU
IF %N%==2 GOTO CLOSE

:AUDIORE
cls
color A
if "%1"=="am_admin" (powershell start -verb runas '%0' am_admin) 
net stop audiosrv
net stop AudioEndPointBuilder
net start AudioEndPointBuilder
net start audiosrv
echo.
echo Your audio drivers have been reset, hope it solved your audio problem!
echo.
pause
GOTO TOOLS

:BATOPEN
cls
color A
start %windir%\explorer.exe "C:\battery-report.html"
pause
echo.
SET /P O=Enter number 1 to return to the previous sub-menu, enter number 2 to return to the main-menu or enter number 3 to exit the script. Enter: 
IF %O%==1 GOTO TOOLS
IF %O%==2 GOTO MENU
IF %O%==3 GOTO CLOSE

:OPENCBSLOG
cls
color A
start %windir%\explorer.exe "C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log"
pause
echo.
SET /P P=Enter number 1 to return to the previous sub-menu, enter number 2 to return to the main-menu or enter number 3 to exit the script. Enter: 
IF %P%==1 GOTO TOOLS
IF %P%==2 GOTO MENU
IF %P%==3 GOTO CLOSE

:NINITE
cls
color A
start "" https://ninite.com/7zip-chrome-edge-vlc/ninite.exe 
pause
echo.
SET /P Q=Enter number 1 to return to the previous sub-menu, enter number 2 to return to the main-menu or enter number 3 to exit the script. Enter: 
IF %Q%==1 GOTO TOOLS
IF %Q%==2 GOTO MENU
IF %Q%==3 GOTO CLOSE

:LICENSE
cls
color A
echo.
echo "Your systems license key:"
wmic path SoftwareLicensingService get OA3xOriginalProductKey
pause
color E
echo.
echo If it didn't showed a key, it is possible that this PC is using a 'illegal' key, or a key that was used for a previous installation of Windows 7/8 - then upgraded to 10/11.
echo.
echo You can also try to use a different script for the license key, you can find it in the 'Scripts' folder in this pcHealth folder!
echo.
SET /p R=If you want to return to the previous sub-menu, enter number 1. To return to the main-menu, enter number 2. To exit the script, enter the number 3. Enter: 
IF %R%==1 GOTO TOOLS
IF %R%==2 GOTO MENU
IF %R%==2 GOTO CLOSE

:BIOSPW
cls
color E
echo.
echo The BIOS Password Recovery tool is a website that can be used to gather/generate a recovery code for the BIOS.
echo.
echo If you don't know how to use this function/website, then 
echo I would suggest that you enter '2' on the next line to learn more.
echo. 
echo The credits for this function and repository goes to the owner: @bacher09
echo.
SET /P SK=Enter number 1 to visit the website, enter number 2 to go to the repository of BIOS-PW and learn more! Enter number 3 to return to the sub-menu, enter number 4 to return to the main-menu or enter number 5 to close the script. Enter: 
IF %SK%==1 start "" https://bios-pw.org && GOTO BIOSPW
IF %SK%==2 start "" https://github.com/bacher09/pwgen-for-bios && GOTO BIOSPW
IF %SK%==3 GOTO TOOLS
IF %SK%==4 GOTO MENU
IF %SK%==5 GOTO CLOSE 

:RESHUT
cls
color A
echo. 
SET /P S=If you want to log off from your PC/Laptop enter number 1, to restart enter number 2, to shutdown enter number 3 and to return to the previous sub-menu enter number 4 or to exit the script... enter number 5. Enter: 
IF %S%==1 GOTO LOGOFF1
IF %S%==2 GOTO RESTART2
IF %S%==3 GOTO SHUTDOWN3
IF %S%==4 GOTO TOOLS
IF %S%==5 GOTO CLOSE

:LOGOFF1
cls
color A 
echo. 
SET /P T=Are you sure that you want to log off your PC? Enter number 1, enter number 2 to return to the previous sub-menu, enter number 3 to return to the main-menu or enter number 4 to exit the script. Enter: 
IF %T%==1 GOTO LOGOFFCONFIRM1
IF %T%==2 GOTO TOOLS
IF %T%==3 GOTO MENU 
IF %T%==4 GOTO CLOSE

:LOGOFFCONFIRM1
cls
color A  
shutdown /l 
EXIT /B

:RESTART2
cls
color A
echo.
SET /P U=Are you sure that you want to restart your PC? Enter number 1, to do so. Enter number 2 to return to the previous sub-menu, enter number 3 to return to the main-menu or enter number 4 to exit the script. Enter: 
IF %U%==1 GOTO RESTARTCONFIRM2
IF %U%==2 GOTO TOOLS
IF %U%==3 GOTO MENU
IF %U%==4 GOTO CLOSE

:RESTARTCONFIRM2
cls
color A 
shutdown /r
EXIT /B

:SHUTDOWN3
cls
color A
echo. 
SET /P V=Are you sure that you want to shutdown your PC? Enter number 1, to continue. Enter number 2 to return to the previous sub-menu, enter number 3 to return to the main-menu or enter number 4 to exit the script. Enter: 
IF %V%==1 GOTO SHUTDOWNCONFIRM3
IF %V%==2 GOTO TOOLS 
IF %V%==3 GOTO MENU
IF %V%==4 GOTO CLOSE

:SHUTDOWNCONFIRM3
cls
color A
shutdown /s
EXIT /B

:PCHEALTHGETVER
cls
color A
echo.
echo Are you sure that you want to download the newest version of pcHealth?
echo.
SET /P AC=If yes, enter the number 1, if not enter number 2 to return to the previous sub-menu. Enter: 
IF %AC%==1 GOTO PCHEALTHGETVERDOWNLOADLINK
IF %AC%==2 GOTO MENU 

:PCHEALTHGETVERDOWNLOADLINK
cls
color A
echo.
echo Your download will start now!
echo.
start "" https://github.com/REALSDEALS/pcHealth/archive/refs/heads/main.zip 
echo.
SET /P AD=To return to the main menu enter 1, to close the script enter 2. Enter: 
IF %AD%==1 GOTO MENU
IF %AD%==2 GOTO CLOSE
 
:HARDINFODOWN
cls
color A
echo.
echo Are you sure that you want to download the newest version of Hardware Info?
echo.
SET /P AE=If yes, enter the number 1, if not enter number 2 to return to the sub-menu. Enter: 
IF %AE%==1 GOTO HARDINFODOWNLOADLINK 
IF %AE%==2 GOTO PROGRAMS

:HARDINFODOWNLOADLINK
cls
color A
echo.
echo Your download will start now; if not click on 'installer' on the download page!
echo.
start "" https://www.fosshub.com/HWiNFO.html?dwl=hwi_726.exe
echo.
SET /P AF=To return to the previous sub-menu enter 1, enter number 2 to return to the main-menu or enter number 3 to exit the script. Enter: 
IF %AF%==1 GOTO PROGRAMS
IF %AF%==2 GOTO MENU
IF %AF%==3 GOTO CLOSE

:ADWCLEANER
cls
color A
echo.
echo Are you sure that you want to download the latest version of ADW Cleaner?
echo. 
SET /P AG=If yes enter the number 1 to start the download, enter number 2 to return to the previous sub-menu. Enter: 
IF %AG%==1 GOTO ADWCLEANERDOWNLOADLINK
IF %AG%==2 GOTO PROGRAMS

:ADWCLEANERDOWNLOADLINK
cls
color A
echo. 
echo Your download will start now!
echo.
start "" https://downloads.malwarebytes.com/file/adwcleaner
echo.
SET /P AH=To return to the previous sub-menu enter 1, enter number 2 to return to the main-menu or enter number 3 to exit the script. Enter: 
IF %AH%==1 GOTO TOOLS
IF %AH%==2 GOTO MENU
IF %AH%==3 GOTO CLOSE

:DISKINFODOWN
cls
color A
echo. 
echo Are you sure that you want to download the latest version of Disk Info?
echo. 
SET /P AI=If yes enter the number 1 to start the download, enter the number 2 to return to the previous sub-menu. Enter: 
IF %AI%==1 GOTO DISKINFODOWNLOADLINK
IF %AI%==2 GOTO PROGRAMS

:DISKINFODOWNLOADLINK
cls
color A
echo.
echo Your download will start now!
start "" https://osdn.net/projects/crystaldiskinfo/downloads/77538/CrystalDiskInfo8_17_4.zip/
echo.
SET /P AJ=To return to the previous sub-menu enter 1, enter number 2 to return to the main-menu or enter number 3 to exit the script. Enter: 
IF %AJ%==1 GOTO TOOLS
IF %AJ%==2 GOTO MENU
IF %AJ%==3 GOTO CLOSE

:DISKMARKDOWN
cls
color A
echo. 
echo Are you sure that you want to download the latest version of Disk Mark?
echo. 
SET /P AK=If yes enter the number 1 to start the download, enter the number 2 to return to the previous sub-menu. Enter: 
IF %AK%==1 GOTO DISKMARKDOWNLOADLINK
IF %AK%==2 GOTO PROGRAMS

:DISKMARKDOWNLOADLINK
cls
color A
echo.
echo Your download will start now!
start "" https://osdn.net/projects/crystaldiskmark/downloads/77539/CrystalDiskMark8_0_4b.zip/
echo.
SET /P AL=To return to the previous sub-menu enter 1, enter number 2 to return to the main-menu or enter number 3 to exit the script. Enter: 
IF %AL%==1 GOTO TOOLS
IF %AL%==2 GOTO MENU
IF %AL%==3 GOTO CLOSE

:PRIMEDOWN
cls
color A
echo. 
echo Are you sure that you want to download the latest version of Prime95? Enter: 
echo. 
SET /P AM=If yes enter the number 1 to start the download, enter the number 2 to return to the previous sub-menu.
IF %AM%==1 GOTO PRIMEDOWNLOADLINK
IF %AM%==2 GOTO PROGRAMS

:PRIMEDOWNLOADLINK
cls
color A
echo.
echo Your download will start now!
start "" https://www.guru3d.com/files-get/prime95-download,3.html
echo.
SET /P AN=To return to the previous sub-menu enter 1, enter number 2 to return to the main-menu or enter number 3 to exit the script. Enter: 
IF %AN%==1 GOTO TOOLS
IF %AN%==2 GOTO MENU
IF %AN%==3 GOTO CLOSE

:CLOSE
EXIT /B
```

**Main goal:**

- I want to make a GUI version of this script.

**Problems or things that I'm struggling with:**

- How can I make commands like batch/ps and vbs run with each other, like for example from a click in the GUI. Because it are all languages on their own, I have now made 3 seperate folders. (The .vbs script is not my own, I got it and changed it a bit)
- A local database for users to run certain test, like the battery-report and save it to a local file/database that users could later acces.
- A kind of version control that when the script (GUI) is launched it would fetch from GitHub to check if there is a new version available.

I'm sorry if I'm asking some dumb questions, I'm trying to teach and help myself by doing some projects for myself. So all help is welcome! The pcHealth repo may be dumb, but a few people do use it :)

Please keep in mind that I'm not a pro, I would consider myself as a complete noob on this subject.

I'm looking forward to your responses though!

~ REALSDEALS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible using python, but with a batch it is not possible.

Comment: Thanks for your anwser Cookie, I really appreciate it! It's sad to see I got some downvotes and that my question is closed... :( 

But again, thanks for anwsering my question. If I can be so free to ask, how can I use python to execute cmd commands?

Comment: Just use:

    ``import os``

# And put in another line

    ``os.system("cmd command")``

Comment: Thank you very much for your reaction, I'm going to try it out! :)